# Switch on an enum

Tags: objective-c, enums, switch-statement

I have the following piece of code:

```
switch (self.status) {
    case refused:
        message=NSLocalizedString(@"booking refused", nil);
        break;
    case accepted:
        message=NSLocalizedString(@"booking accepted", nil);
        break;
    case taxiAborted:
        message=NSLocalizedString(@"booking aborted", nil);
        break;
    case near:
        message=NSLocalizedString(@"booking aborted", nil);
        break;
    case completed:
        message=NSLocalizedString(@"booking completed", nil);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

that never enters the interior of the switch: neither hitting the default case nor the correct value. In my case self.status had value 'active' that is part of the following enumeration:

```
typedef enum {
requested = 0,
refused = 1,
    accepted =2,
    taxiAborted=3,
    near = 4,
    running= 5,
    completed = 6,
    userAborted=7
} statuses;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I don't see `active` in that enum declaration. Could you please clarify?

Comment: If it never even enters the switch, to the point where it never triggers the `default` case, are you sure it's even getting to the switch to begin with?

Comment: You question makes no sense. There is no value "active" in the enum - you mean "accepted"? How do you know you did not hit the default case? I usually put an assert there like "assert(!"switch case not found");" to force a crash during development.

Comment: have you log self.status before switch?

Comment: The debugger will not *necessarily* enter an empty `default:`, try adding `NSLog(@"Default");` before the `break`.

Comment: Yes, it was to be 'accepted', sorry. At any rate I did not pay too much attention given even the default was not reached. Regarding my knowledge of the flow of course I set a breakpoints at the start of the switch and again in the cases and the default. The first one was reached, the latter not so and that confounded me somewhat, yet...

I will try adding a command in the default - thanks Das - I was not aware putting a breakpoint in a break alone in a case did not have effects with the debugger - and double-check the entered values.

Comment: As a matter of fact, once I added a command in the default case, it enters it; nonetheless when I have enum 'accepted' it keeps on going to the default instead of going to the right case. Is there the possibility the strings in the switches remain as such instead of turning into enum? And in that case how may force them to be used as enums?

Comment: What is very strange is that, even if I uses a series of if, control always enter the case with associated value 0, although the debugger correctly reports the accepted one with associated value 2.

Comment: The problem was actually I used a global value by the same name rather than the parameter; why the debugger gave me the correct value instead of un undefined one rests a mystery.